# @XmlList represenattion in XML metadata JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I am using MOXY as my JAXB implementation for marshalling/unmarshalling.

I have a class which has `List` as one of the member variables:

```
public class Model {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String time;
    @XmlList
    protected List<String> labels;
}
```

I want the xml conversion after marshalling as:

```
<time>25042015</time>
<lbl>label1 label2 label3</lbl>
```

So I want the `label` modified to `lbl` and if there is an empty list, I don't want it to be shown in the XML.

It's a legacy class so I am not editing my POJO and I am providing a extrernal meta-data file:

```
    <java-type name="Modal">
                <java-attributes>

                    <xml-element java-attribute="labels" name="lbl" >
                    </xml-element>

                 </java-attributes>
   </java-type>
```

But with this the xml is formed as:

```
<time>25042015</time>
<lbl>label1</lbl>
<lbl>label2</label>
<lbl>label3</lbl>
```

So I added `xml-list="true"` in the metatdata file:

```
<xml-element java-attribute="labels" name="lbl" xml-list="true"></xml-element>
```

This solves my problem of making XML like:  `<lbl>label1 label2 label3</lbl>`

But if my list is empty : `labels = new ArrayList()`,

adds an empty list to XML which I don't want. Something like:

```
<time>25042015</time>
<lbl></lbl>
```

Empty list does not come if there is no `xml-list="true"`.

How to remove the empty list from the XML ??

I tried adding an `XmlAdpater` so that if list is empty make it null (thus it will not appear in XML):

```
public class ListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List, List>{

    @Override
    public List unmarshal(List v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("********Inside ListAdapter UNMARSHALL********");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public List marshal(List v) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("********Inside ListAdapter MARSHALL********");

        if(v != null && v.isEmpty())
            return null;

        return v;
    }

}
```

But this gives an Exception:

```
12:49:18,893 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
12:49:18,893 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Exception Description: XmlList is only allowed on a collection or array property but [labels] is not a collection or array property.
12:49:18,893 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)  - with linked exception:
12:49:18,893 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) [Exception [EclipseLink-50018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
```

Comment: Make the list null explicitly  (when it's empty) and don't use the adapter.

Comment: @dsp_user: The POJO is getting set at the backend, so I am getting a filled POJO which I have to marshall. So thus was trying to explicitly set it to null inside adapter

Comment: You can still check the list before you marshall the POJO and set it to null if it's empty, can't you?

Comment: I am marshaling a bunch of 40POJOs which have a hierarchical relationship between them. So there will be many lists and calling so many getters for all lists will be cumbersome

Comment: Did you try using XmlElement instead of XmlList (because you're getting an exception on XmlList)?

Comment: I didn't get this ? I added : `<xml-element java-attribute="labels" name="lbl" >`
                    </xml-element>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124519/discussion-between-siddharth-trikha-and-dsp-user).